# NEMA 17 Stepper motor + Arduino Mega + driver doesn't move using GRBL and UGS

Tags: arduino-mega, stepper-motor

3x NEMA 17 Stepper Motors: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00PNEQKC0/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00PNEQKC0)

3x DM542T Stepper Driver: https://www.omc-stepperonline.com/download/DM542T.pdf

Power supply: 12V, 30A

Arduino Mega: [https://www.amazon.com/ARDUINO-MEGA-2560-REV3-A000067/dp/B0046AMGW0/ref=sr_1_3?dchild=1&keywords=arduino+mega&qid=1623258848&sr=8-3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0046AMGW0)

---

I am currently trying to use the GRBL (Mega version 1.1f - https://github.com/gnea/grbl-Mega) and Universal G-code sender (UGS classic version 2.0.7 - https://github.com/winder/Universal-G-Code-Sender) to program my 3 NEMA 17 Stepper motors, but none of the motors move. I have tried powering just one NEMA motor using a simple arduino code successfully.
I successfully uploaded the GRBL Mega software onto the arduino and connected that with the UGS. Upon using the toggle buttons, the status shows that the coordinates are jogging, but my stepper motor does not move. I probed the pins with an oscilloscope as well and read a continuous 5V on pins 11 and 12, which I don't exactly understand. Shouldn't there be pulses sent to the pins used, not continuous voltage?

Here are my current connections:
V+ on driver is connected to V+ on power supply
V- on power supply is connected to GND on arduino and GND, DIR-, PUL- on the driver
The other four wires are connected from motor to driver.
DIR+ is connected to pin 5, and PUL+ is connected to pin 2

Please suggest anything I can try!

Comment: There's... a lot of things you could try. There's at *least* two layers of troubleshooting: circuit (which we can't see) and GRBL config, which includes both the GRBL compilation itself, e.g., everything custom required for the driver, and the customization doable once it's loaded (neither of which we can see).

Comment: Solved! I mistakenly assumed pinouts were the same on the Arduino Uno vs. Mega configurations. Changing the pins worked!

Comment: can you please provide pinouts that has to be changed.